# While loop not cancelling out

Tags: java, eclipse

I've ran into a weird issue.

I'm trying to make this code loop constantly until the user enters 4; when the user enters 4, I want to make it so that 'Quit_Detect' is set to false.

For some reason, it doesn't let me do that. The code still continuously loops until it is stopped manually.

Below is all of the code that I have used for this program along with some comments.

```
import java.util.Scanner;                               // Imports the scanner utility.

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);    // Creates a new scanner.
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        boolean Quit_Detect;
        Quit_Detect = true;
        while (Quit_Detect = true)
        {
            int input;                                      // States that input will have a datatype of 'int', or integer. Or, a whole number.
            System.out.println("Please input your option.");
            System.out.println("1. Door with a crack in it");
            System.out.println("2. Normal Wooden Door");
            System.out.println("3. Turn around");
            System.out.println("4. Quit");
            input = Reader.nextInt();                       // Has the user define what the variable 'input' will be set to.
            switch (input)                                  // Uses the Variable 'input' to detect what case to follow.
            {
                case 1:System.out.println("First Option");
                       break;
                case 2:System.out.println("Second Option");
                       break;
                case 3:System.out.println("Third Option");
                       break;
                case 4:Quit_Detect = false;
                       break;
                default:System.out.println("Invalid option.");  //Prints this if the user inputs any number other than 1, 2, or 3.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(Quit_Detect = true)` is suspicious

Comment: I think you should write `while (Quit_Detect == true)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

`while (Quit_Detect)`

instead of:

`while (Quit_Detect = true)`

The first statement checks if `Quit_Detect` is true where the second sets the value of `Quit_Detect` to true.